# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed? Also changed to unsignedBigInteger

Tags: mysql, laravel

Have here problem of **foreign key** and couldn't find any solution
Here is the problem

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `pamir_culture`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint
> `post_category_fk` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories`
> (`id`))

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->index('category_id', 'post_category_idx');
        $table->foreign('category_id', 'post_category_fk')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that categories table is already made by the time posts table is being created. Use the file names for that, like:

> 2022_08_29_104452_create_categories_table.php

> 2022_08_29_104458_create_posts_table.php

Cheers